# How to configure VLC auto-resizing for low-resolution files

Tags: windows-10, video, resolution, vlc-media-player

I play a mix of 320p/480p/720p content via VLC, and each time I open one of the smaller resolutions for playing, VLC makes the window small - can I configure it such that if the content is less than say 500p, automatically set the zoom level to 200%, such that the windows becomes roughly the same size as it is for 720p content at 100%?

note: I am not looking for a fixed window size, as that would destroy the scaling from 4:3 video and 16:9, and would greatly prefer to have it a fixed % zoom, rather than a fixed window size that then leads to odd-sized zooms.

Comment: @harrymc windows, but if there I'd a Linux option id also be interested

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible using the following tools:

- [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
- `mediainfo.dll`, distributed with most video players and codecs,
  but also [directly available](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download/Windows).
  As AutoHotkey is 32-bit, use the 32-bit version.

The skeleton AutoHotkey script below can be part of an `.ahk` file for solving the
problem:

```
video = "file-path"
DllCall( "LoadLibrary", Str,"MediaInfo.Dll" )
hnd := MediaInfo_New()
MediaInfo_Open( hnd, video )
height := MediaInfo_Get( hnd, 1,0, "Height", 1 )
MediaInfo_Close( hnd )

if (height < 500)
  Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --zoom=2 %video%
else
  Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" %video%

MediaInfo_New() {
 Return DllCall( "mediainfo\MediaInfo" ( A_IsUnicode ? "" : "A" ) "_New" )
}

MediaInfo_Open( hnd, MediaFile ) {
 Return DllCall( "mediainfo.dll\MediaInfo" ( A_IsUnicode ? "" : "A" ) "_Open", UInt,hnd
               , Str,MediaFile, UInt )
}

MediaInfo_Get( hnd, StrK=0, StrN=0, Comm="", InfK=0, Srch=0 ) {
 Return DllCall( "mediainfo.dll\MediaInfo" ( A_IsUnicode ? "" : "A" ) "_Get", UInt,hnd
               , Int,StrK, Int,StrN, Str,Comm, Int,InfK, Int,Sech, Str )
}

MediaInfo_Close( hnd ) {
 Return DllCall( "mediainfo\MediaInfo" ( A_IsUnicode ? "" : "A" ) "_Close", UInt,hnd )
}
```

This script is based on the AutoHotkey forum post
[Get video length and resolution](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/100404-get-video-length-and-resolution/).
The script in the post also shows how to create a AutoHotkey window, which operates
on files dropped on this window.

Please note that I have not tested the above script.

Comment: I haven't used AutoHotkey before & am still learning it, right now I'm not sure how to get it to run the script when I play a video file (or launch VLC when I try to play a video with the .ahk script)

Comment: See [Command Line Parameters](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#cmd). You may also use parts of the link to set up a little widow for dropping videos to be handled, in case you do lots of these. AutoHotkey is an extensive tool, worth learning, with lots of help available. Just google for "AutoHotkey verb" or similar to find help. For hard problems, the user forum is pretty helpful.